# Can we create product attribute without select options, and add it later?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, setup-script

I have the following setup file in my custom module on `Vendor\Module\Setup\InstallData.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    protected $setup;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->setup = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $new_product_attrs = [
            "field_1" => [
                "label" => "Field 1",
                "type" => "int",
                "input" => "select",
                "source" => "\Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Option"
            ],
            "field_2 " => [
                "label" => "Field 2",
                "type" => "int",
                "input" => "text"
            ],
        ];
        //Create product attributes
        foreach ($new_product_attrs as $code => $attr){
            $this->createProductAttribute($setup, $code, $attr);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }

    private function createProductAttribute($setup, $attr_code, $attr_details){
        $setup = $this->setup->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attr = [
            "type"     => $attr_details["type"],
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => $attr_details["label"],
            "input"    => $attr_details["input"],
            "source"   => "",
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default"  => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            'user_defined' => true,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
        ];
        if (isset($attr_details["backend"])){
            $attr['backend'] = $attr_details["backend"];
        }
        if (isset($attr_details["source"])){
            $attr['source'] = $attr_details["source"];
        }
        if (isset($attr_details["option_values"])){
            $attr['option'] = [
                'values' => $attr_details["option_values"]
            ];
        }
        $setup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attr_code, $attr);
    }
}
```

And for `Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Option.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Option extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
    * Get all options
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options=[
            ['label' => '--Select Options--', 'value' => ''],
        ];
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve flat column definition
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColumns()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        return [
            $attributeCode => [
                'unsigned' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'extra' => null,
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Custom Attribute Options  ' . $attributeCode . ' column',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I can create the attribute successfully, but on `field_1`, I found there are **no options available** even I go to **Store->Attribute->Product** and create new options for `field_1`. Which step I've done wrong? I don't mind drop the attribute and create that attribute again as the website is still testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see             `"source"   => "",` is empty on `$arr=[]` even though you have source model in `$new_product_attrs` so I think this is creaitng Issue just try to pass source model If you are getting in `$attr_details`

Comment: The `source` will be set if `$new_product_attrs` contains `"source"`. Obviously `field_1` contains `"source"`